# What is the right usage: Attend at gym or train at gym?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I want to ask a friend what is the name of the gym he is visiting. Which is the grammatically correct to ask

```
What is the name of the gym you attend?
```

or

```
What is the name of the gym you train?
```

or

```
What is the name of the gym you practise?
```

I do not want to ask him

```
What is the name of the gym you are visiting?
What is the name of the gym you are going to?
```

Comment: it's "name of the gym where you train" etc.  this is an ELL question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the three sentences you provided, the only one that is correct is:

> What is the name of the gym you attend?

You don't *train* or *practise* a gym, you train or practise *at* a gym. Note that this wording is rather formal.

You could also ask:

> What is the name of your gym?

Although the gym does not belong to you, this would be perfectly understood.

Also:

> Which gym do you go to?
>
> Which gym do you train at?

Comment: marv dude - are we meant to answer ELL questions?

Comment: @Joe Not _answer_ answer: <<And we write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to _become_ a topic. Thank you. – RegDwigнt>> (I know your question was rhetorical, but I wanted to use a lexical clone, and use Reg's quote.)

Comment: As I understand it, the philosophy of SE sites is to self-regulate through up/down votes and consensus close-votes. Starving an easily answerable question, or indirectly criticising the OP by questioning someone who *does* answer seems both passive-aggressive and somewhat churlish to me. If you feel strongly enough about the question to question me, why didn't you downvote it? I cannot determine whether this question should have been here or elsewhere as it does not appear to contradict the rules, so I leave that to others. Feel free to address the issue with the OP.